# Create several Procedure in one notepad

Tags: sql-server

I am using vb.net and in my project i want to create store procedure in single sql file but system reads as single procedure..So

like this is an sql file..

create proc aa
...
...

create proc bb
...
...

for to solve this problem what can i do ? Please forward me the solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 3):

The question is not entirely clear, but if you are using MS SQL Server you may be able to add `GO` to the end of each command.